# Developing Apps for the Cloud

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, azure, apps-development

I an new to Developing SharePoint solutions to the cloud. I have been having the following questions.

1. What are the clouds supporting SharePoint deployments (Maybe like Azure, SharePoint-Online, etc...)
2. From what i hear, custom coding is restricted in cloud applications. Can an application which has custom coding (eg. like sending mails, etc..) be migrated to a cloud based Apps.

How can this be best achieved in the cloud ?

Would be grateful if you could shed some light into this !!

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 (formerly known as SharePoint online) is a cloud counterpart of SharePoint on-premises. There two types of apps which are cloud based: AutoHosted apps and Provider hosted apps.

> The main difference is that with auto-hosted apps all Windows Azure
>   and Windows Azure SQL Database components are provisioned for you when
>   the app is installed and the Windows Azure Web Sites infrastructure
>   handles load balancing and other important maintenance tasks for you.
>   When using provider-hosted apps, you're responsible for provisioning
>   what's necessary to support the app.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100384/sharepoint-2013-auto-hosted-app-vs-provider-hosted-app-in-azure

No server side code can be written in apps whether they are SharePoint hosted or cloud hosted. However, managed client object model code can be written in cloud hosted apps. So, before converting any solution to app one needs to look into the functionality provided by the solution and check if it can be delivered using client object mode.